# split column into character and numeric in R

Tags: r

I split a data frame into `X` and `Y`. `X` has one column, `Y` has about `100`.

```
x <- subset(tbl, , select = ordernum)
y <- subset(tbl, select = -c(ordernum, paid1num, 
          weight, returnnum, order_only, multi_dep, sequence_id))
```

Next I correlate `X` with *each column* in `Y` which produces a `frame` with `100 columns` and `a single row`.

```
corr <- cor(x,y)
```

Next I transpose,

```
corr.t <- t(corr)
```

and the (truncated) result looks like this:

```
                                   ordernum
HH_AFFORD_MOMS_BUY_GREEN      -0.0021281583
HH_AFFORD_SPORTS              -0.0047221159
HH_AFFORD_CLASSICAL_MUSIC     -0.0006594956
HH_AFFORD_HOME_DECOR           0.0052106766
```

I would like to split this single column, called `ordernum`, into 2 columns. A `character` field with the variable names, and a `numeric` with the correlations.

I appreciate any guidance. Perhaps if I use `lm`, instead of `cor`?

Answer (score 5):

The output that you have stored as `corr.t` is a `matrix`, and the "variable names" you mention are the *row* names of the matrix, accessible using `rownames()`.

To get your desired output, you can just do:

```
data.frame(id = rownames(corr.t), val = c(t(corr.t)))
```

A more general solution--applicable when your matrix is more than just one column--would be:

```
data.frame(ID = rownames(your-matrix), 
           as.data.frame(your-matrix, 
                         row.names = 1:nrow(your-matrix)))
```

The last line, `row.names = 1:nrow(your-matrix)`, removes the row names from the output; they are no longer needed since they are now part of your data frame.

---

For what it's worth, you don't actually need to specifically transpose your data to get to the output you desire. Here's an example with one of the datasets available with R that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve:

```
(mycor <- cor(swiss[, 1], swiss[, 2:5]))
#      Agriculture Examination  Education  Catholic
# [1,]   0.3530792  -0.6458827 -0.6637889 0.4636847

# Now, make it into a data.frame
data.frame(id = colnames(mycor), val = as.vector(mycor))
#            id        val
# 1 Agriculture  0.3530792
# 2 Examination -0.6458827
# 3   Education -0.6637889
# 4    Catholic  0.4636847
```

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this just to add a little more explanation than "just do"...

Comment: please feel free to edit!

Comment: I think I overdid it. Maybe it's time I called it a night ;)

Comment: what the...!!?! yes, indeed! :P

Comment: Thank you very much. You completely solved my problem, and have helped me learn some R.